# В Intellij IDEA при добавлении нового Class нет возможности сделать его static

Tags: java, intellij-idea

На **Ubuntu 19.04** в среде разработки **Intellij IDEA**

при создании `class (static)` после ввода символа `s` не выполняется автодополнение.

В случае если я сам пишу `static` он будет подчеркнут с ошибкой:
 *Make "Test" not static*.

Прошу помочь разобраться в проблеме.
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Статическим классом в Java может быть только вложенный класс (класс внутри другого класса).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , погуглил разобрался!Всем Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в Java вы не можете создать static класс сам по себе. Это ключевое слово используется для "отделения" экземпляра вложенного класса от экземпляра внешнего класса. Соответственно, только для вложенных классов оно и применимо

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , погуглил разобрался!Всем Спасибо